# Is there a such thing as an equivalence class of a set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

I am familiar of the equivalence class on an element in a set (given some equivalence relation), but is there a such thing as equivalence class of a set?

I ran into this reading paper *Encoding Data Structures by Rajeev Raman*: "Given a set of objects S, and a set of queries Q, consider the equivalence class C on S induced by Q, where two objects from S are equivalent if they provide the same answer to all queries in Q."

Comment: I see no equivalence class of a set here, but an equivalence class of an object in a set (of course this object may be a set itself).

Comment: Not clear... the equiv class is defined **on** the set $S$ i.e. the elements of $S$ are partitioned into disjoint subsets of $S$ such that two elements of $S$ are in teh same subset (equiv class) iff they provide the same answer to all queries in $Q$.

Comment: The author most likely meant to write “… consider the equivalence *relation* $C$ on $S$ induced by $Q$ …” On the other hand, the $C$ seems to be suggestive notation for “class”. Can you link the paper?

Comment: I think they meant either "consider the equivalence *relation*" or "consider *an* equivalence class" (i.e. the equivalence class of some arbitrary element of $S$).

Comment: @k.stm Here is the paper in question:  https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-15612-5_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be any different from how we normally talk about equivalence classes:  the author defines a binary relation over a set $S$, where any two objects from the set are related 'if they provide the same answer to all queries'. This relation is obviously reflexive, symmetric, and transitive, and hence is an equivalence relation. And the equivalence class $C$ is still defined relative to any object $o$ in the set, in that it is the set of all objects from that set standing in that equivalence relation to the object $o$.  So this is all still relative to elements of the set.